# How to calculate sample size in binominal distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, confidence-interval

I have a task that is very time consuming if it were to be done for all cases. Let's say I have X items and I need to check them. Some turn out to be type A, others turn out to be type B. And I need to know what is the percentage of those of type A. (Is it Bernoulli?) For the sake of time I can test a small portion of X. I need to determine how large a sample I should test to get a 95% confidence interval.
I have read and even found an example that deals with a similar case to mine and I am deploying that Wald Interval is something I should be interested in.

$$p = \hat{p} \pm z \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$$

so I know that $z$ shall be: $z=1.96$.

From above equation I can calculate $n$ in that case with:

$$ n = \frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{(\frac{p-\hat{p}}{z})^2}$$

In the example I found, someone assumed that the proportion is 15% (0.15) and interval width +- 0.2%. So the confidence interval is 0.148 to 0.152 (this is p without hat). But after all, this 15% is just an assumption. Taking for example 30% we have a completely different result, different $n$. How to interpret it?

In another example I found it says that Cochran's sample size formula was used (without specifying which one). Assumed confidence interval of 95% with an error margin of approximately 0.6%. The result was that the sample must be 27000. I tested various cases in Excel and according to me in this case the proportion $\hat{p}=0.5$ was assumed, then the sample comes out exactly 26677.78 which was rounded to 27000 for certainty.

[image: my calculations for second example]

Please help.

Comment: "Let's say I have X total elements and by checking it turns out that one has trait a and the other has trait b". Huh...?  "The *other*"?   Please explain.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to determine the needed sample size to compare whether the proportion of a certain trait between these two groups is statistically different? I think that the problem is that you want to abstract your sketched study design, but you are missing out on a couple of technical terms to make it clear. Can you be more specific in the actual proposed testing?

Comment: Sorry, I used translator. I edited the text, now maybe it's clearer?

Comment: @AntoniParellada I need to determine smallest possible sample size that I can test and get 95% confidence interval.

Comment: Are you looking into whether there is any difference in the percentage of good pianists between a sample of Polish women and a sample of French women? I understand that you want the sample size but to do what exactly...

Comment: Yyyy..no :D I am testing electronic component.

Comment: I understand you are doing something else, and you probably don't want to give us all the details. What I am proposing is that you hold off on all the statistical lingo for now, and formulate the question in a way that it is understandable to all. A way of doing so is making up a silly, but clear equivalent toy example.

Comment: In any event, I think that all the answers you may ever need on categorical data can be found on Alan Agresti's book *An Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis*. Best of luck!

Comment: Let's say memory has a part of bits =1 and the rest are 0. I need to test all its bits which takes about 3 seconds per bit and I need to find out how many of them are 1. So I'm wondering if by testing some part of all bits I can give a 95% confidence interval for the proportion of bits = 1 to all bits.

Comment: So you are looking at all bits of duration $3$ whatever that means, and you want to estimate the true proportion of $1$-bits among them? If so why don't you look into the [minimum sample size for estimating a population proportion](https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_Statistics/Book%3A_Introductory_Statistics_(Shafer_and_Zhang)/07%3A_Estimation/7.04%3A_Sample_Size_Considerations)?

Comment: Thank you. It was useful.

Comment: One common practice is to assume $p=1/2$ for the purpose of estimating sample size, since this is the "worst case", with maximum variance.

Comment: It is reasonable to do a 'pilot' study to get a rough idea of $p$ to use in the equation for judging the number $n$ of items for the main study. // The Wald CI for the binomial success parameter is 'asymptotic' (intended to be used only for large samples --- at least several hundred). For about 25 years now, the use of the Wald CI for small samples has been deprecated. Your first job is to decide whether to use something like Agresti CIs or Jeffreys CIs instead. // Maybe see Wikipedia page on CIs for binomial proportions.